# NetworkX From_Pandas_dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have an error with NetworkX which says 'module' has no attribute 'from_pandas_dataframe.'

I have a dataframe called nflroster that is format as:

```
Index   . . . Player           Team       Year

0       . . . Player1          Team1      2014

1       .  . .Player2          Team1      2014


2       . . . Player3          Team2      2014
.
.       . . .   .                .         .
```

So according to the documentation here [networkx documentation](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html) this following line should work

```
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(nflroster,str, 'Team')
```

However when I run this in Ipy notebook I run into the error, 'module' object has no attribute 'from_pandas_dataframe'.

I import the following

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
```

Comment: Have you checked your version?  It looks like that function was added in version 2.0, you may be using an older version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem here. This is how I solved it:

Try installing networkx from source instead of installing it through pip.

**Source Install Step by Step**

```
    Download the source (tar.gz or zip file) from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx/ or get the latest development version from https://github.com/networkx/networkx/
    Unpack and change directory to the source directory (it should have the files README.txt and setup.py).
    Run python setup.py install to build and install
```

Notice that this specific function **From_Pandas_dataframe** will be installed in  convert_matrix.py file at the networkx folder.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem, after installing from source it still return the error.

Answer (score 2):

You probably installed an incorrect version of networkx. You probably should check whether you have 1.10.0 <= see [history here](http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/api_1.10.html)

Comment: You have to download from source instead of pip. I'm not sure why, but I continuously have problem with pip. u/Gustavo Avila/ has the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

If we look in the networkx's build folder, in **__init__.py**, we see an import from networkx.convert_matrix. Looking thru the **convert_matrix.py** file we can see the following allowed external dependencies:

```
__all__ = ['from_numpy_matrix', 'to_numpy_matrix',
           'from_pandas_adjacency', 'to_pandas_adjacency',
           'from_pandas_edgelist', 'to_pandas_edgelist',
           'to_numpy_recarray',
           'from_scipy_sparse_matrix', 'to_scipy_sparse_matrix',
           'from_numpy_array', 'to_numpy_array']
```

As you can see, from_pandas_dataframe does not exist. Although this might have been in the [1.10 version](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html).

So in the end, always keep a keen eye on the version number.

Answer (score 0):

yet another way to search for a method in Networkx API:

```
In [199]: [m for m in nx.__dir__() if 'pandas' in m]
Out[199]:
['from_pandas_adjacency',
 'to_pandas_adjacency',
 'from_pandas_edgelist',
 'to_pandas_edgelist']
```